# Tmux: How to paste during copy mode?

Tags: tmux, copy-paste

In copy mode I can copy interesting text. I can also search for some other text.

But how can I paste the text I just copied into search input to find other occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

In your `.tmux.conf`

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi p paste-buffer \; send-keys -X cancel
```

Now when you press `p` you paste your code, and go back to edition mode.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for - I need to paste into search input without exiting the copy mode. Like, select some text, copy and search for more occurrences of that text. On the other hand, I can copy into clipboard, exit, enter copy mode again and paste - but I lose cursor position.